# How to generate .deb from catkin workspace in ROS

Tags: ros, deb, catkin

I can compile and install ROS package in the catkin workspace in ROS. How can I export the package in catkin workspace to a .deb file so I can install and use it on the other machines?

My ROS version is ROS Indigo and OS version is Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - I think the [ROS build farm](http://wiki.ros.org/buildfarm) would be a good starting point and solution for that. You cannot create a .deb as you said but, you can create a source closed ROS packages

> The ROS build farm is also designed to enable deploying a custom build farm. This can be useful to release closed-source packages, build for platforms and architectures not provided by the official ROS build farm, and/or customize any part of the process to specific needs.

Take a look here for a better [overview](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/blob/master/doc/index.rst).

2 - Another approach would be using a [CMake install](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace#Installing_Packages). Although this will require the same architecture and ROS Distro between both your platforms and a location that can be the same for both machines.

```
Define a CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX for some location like: /opt/your_ros_install.
Run sudo make install to allow installing there.
Copy the install directory from machine A to machine B, using scp or tar or some other technique.
```

To run your installed ROS packages on either machine: source /opt/your_ros_install/setup.bash.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a step-by-step guide of doing it using [ROS bloom](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom):

1. **Navigate to your package path**

   `cd /path/to/package`
2. **Use ROS bloom to create the .deb file**

   `bloom-generate rosdebian --os-name ubuntu --ros-distro kinetic fakeroot debian/rules binary`

* *If your ROS distribution is different from Kinetic, replace kinetic with your distribution*

3. **Copy the .deb file to the other machine, and in its folder type**

   `sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb`

   this will install the package on that machine, and you are now able to use it like any other ROS package

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post: [Generate .deb from ROS package](http://answers.ros.org/question/173804/generate-deb-from-ros-package/)
Use the following commands:

```
path-of-your-package$ bloom-generate rosdebian --os-name ubuntu --ros-distro kinetic

$fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by formatting it (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Also I think Wennn is using ROS Indigo, so shouldn't your command contain `--ros-distro indigo`?